# Is it useless to drip Vitamin D drops on your tongue?

Tags: medications, micronutrients, vitamin-d

One celebrity doctor in my country says that **Vitamin D can be absorbed only in the small intestine** and that dropping Vitamin D drops on your tongue is therefore useless, because most of the liquid will never reach your small intestine. He suggests that people use vitamin D only in pill form, so that the pill will have time to travel through your stomach.

Yet, the bottle of my vitamin D drops explicitly says that the drops should be dripped on the tongue.

Comment: See the comment I posted on your other question today. Needs prior research.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you! I will be back after having done more research.

Comment: @CareyGregory: frankly this q seems reasonably well researched for a question: expert? claim, counter-checked against a possibly reasonable/common information source (although it's unclear if the packaging was from a more reputable medication company or some--possibly more obscure supplements--company). Anymore research and one basically ends up writing the answer themselves.

Comment: @CareyGregory: also, e.g. [FAQ from Yale](https://www.yalemedicine.org/stories/vitamin-d-myths-debunked/) on vit D doesn't address this particular issue, so it's not common one discussed.

Comment: @Fizz A "celebrity doctor" equates to someone like Dr. Oz in my mind. And the packaging of an unknown product could be anything, as you noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Vitamin D oil drops are just as effective as tablets. Well they have the oil which helps the Vitamin D absorb since D is fat soluble I guess. https://vitamindwiki.com/tiki-download_wiki_attachment.php?attId=13764&download=y

> We
>   compared the effectiveness of tablets versus oil in raising S-25-hydroxyvitaminD(S-25-OHD) in plasma
>   by re-analyzing data from a previously performed observational study in which immunodeficient
>   patients with S-25-OHD concentrations <75 nmol/L were randomly prescribed vitamin D tablets
>   (1600 IU/day) or vitamin D oil-drops (1500 IU/day) for twelve months. Tablets and oil were compared
>   for the effect on S-25-OHD concentrations after 3–5 months and antibiotic use. Results: Data on
>   S-25-OHD after  3 months was available for 137 patients treated with tablets and 69 with oil drops.
>   Both groups exhibited a significant increase in S-25-OHD—oil-drops from 55 to 86 nmol/L and tablets
>   from 52 to 87 nmol/L—with no difference between groups (p = 0.77).

"Are Vitamin D Tablets and Oil Drops Equally
Eective in Raising S-25-Hydroxyvitamin D
Concentrations? A Post-Hoc Analysis of an
Observational Study on Immunodeficient Patients", *Nutrients*, published April, 2020.

Comment: Also from a [2017 review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5643801/) adding vitamin D to a fat matrix worked better bioavailability-wise than e.g. adding it to a protein matrix.

Comment: Likewise a [2018 systematic review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29025082).